# Calling Deployed API from each server in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elb

Assuming an web application is deployed in Amazon EC2 instance(say in 5 instances/servers) behind Elastic Load Balancer(ELB).

I want to call an API in deployed web application in each server to do some admin level operation in each instance.
eg : https://testapplicaiton/doadminupdate

How can i invoke this API in each server? Can i use AWS API to get list of server/ip address from ELB and invoke API in each instance by http://instance:8080/doadminupdate ? Or is there any provision in ELB or AWS itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i invoke this API in each server? Can i use AWS API to get
>   list of server/ip address from ELB and invoke API in each instance by
>   http://instance:8080/doadminupdate ?

Yes, that is a valid way to accomplish your requirement.

> Or is there any provision in ELB or AWS itself?

No, the ELB will only send a request to a single instance. It won't fan-out the request.

Alternatively, you might look into configuring each server to subscribe to an SNS topic on startup, and send your admin requests to the SNS topic, which will fan out the message to all subscribers.

Comment: If it is in a VPC, will i still be able to access  http ://instance:8080/doadminupdate ?

Comment: If the instances are in a public subnet of the VPC, and you have port 8080 open in the security group that is assigned to the instances, then yes you can access that address. If not, then no. Alternatively, you could call the API endpoints from an instance that is also in the VPC, like a bastion host, and keep the instances inaccessible from outside the VPC.